# Heat map on top of line plot in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't figure out a good way to plot a heat map on top of a line in pyplot. Just for clarification, if I have an array where the first two columns represent x-y data and the third column represents some sort of intensity:

```
array = ([0 , 0 , 100],[1 , 1 , 90 ],[2 , 4 , 60 ],[3 , 9 , 90 ],[4 , 16 , 40])
```

For this example, I chose a parabola. I would like each line segment of the parabola to be colored according to intensity of the third column. Is there a good way to do this? Cheers!

Comment: There is **[an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)** on the matplotlib page showing how to do this. In case this doesn't help can you [edit] your question and say why?!